# Javascript function for photo gallery

Tags: javascript, html, image, function

I'm building a static page where I have an image and 2 arrows (one on the left of the image and one on the right).
By clicking the arrow another image would appear, like in a photo gallery. There's only 4 images in total, which I would keep in the site folder on my computer. Basically the arrows should allow the user to cycle between the images, by pressing the right arrow or the left arrow.

**I have an array of images:**

```
var imageArray = new Array();
imageArray[0] = new Image(); imageArray[0].src = 'image1.png';
imageArray[1] = new Image(); imageArray[1].src = 'image2.png';
imageArray[2] = new Image(); imgArray[2].src = 'image3.png';
imageArray[3] = new Image(); imageArray[3].src = 'image4.png';
```

**And the two arrows:**

```
<div id="apDiv1"style="display:none"><img src="arrow left.png" width="125" height="74" onClick="SOMETHING">/div>

<div id="apDiv2"style="display:none"><img src="arrow right.png" width="125" height="74" onClick="SOMETHING">/div
```

I want to make onClick to call a function that shows the next (or previous) image.

How can I do this? I though of a sort of toggle function but that would work poorly.

And also, can I set up a starting image like:

```
<div id="apDiv3"style="display:none"><img src="image1.png" width="200" height="200">/div>
```

Comment: so you want someone to write the content of `SOMETHING` for you, if i understand correctly?

Comment: Not all of it, just the parts I though important to the matter :)

Comment: Not write, just give me some tips on how to do it, since my idea of toggle function isn't working

Comment: @ipg24 I mean you have incorrect HTML opening/closing tag.

Comment: Forgot to put the </img> when writing here

Comment: That too :P sorry, I didn't type it correctly. But I have it correct on my working file :)

Comment: Do you use jQuery in your project or you need it in plain JavaScript?

Comment: I can use anything, what matters to me is the reasoning behind it and the design of the page itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TO Move Forward (Forward Click)***

**css:**

```
.show {
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Now, suppose you have a **parent div with all image divs** like this

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div id='image-1' class='show'><img src="image1.png" width="200" height="200"></div>
    <div id='image-2' class='hide'><img src="image2.png" width="200" height="200"></div>
    <div id='image-3' class='hide'><img src="image3.png" width="200" height="200"></div>
    //and so on...
</div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
onclick: function() {
    var images = $('.parent').find('div');
    for(var i = 0; i< images.length; i++) {
        if($(images[i]).hasClass('show')) {
            $(images[i]).removeClass('show');
            $(images[i]).addClass('hide');
            if(i === images.length -1) {
                $(images[0]).removeClass('hide');
                $(images[0]).addClass('show');
            } else {
                $(images[0]).removeClass('show');
                $(images[0]).addClass('hide');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, implement for back arrow click

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Understood everything, except the CSS... Should I put that on the CSS of each image?

Comment: umm..Do something like this in your html head-- <head>
<style>
.show {
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>

Comment: You just need to add these classes to your css file.. that is it and the browser will know what to do :)

Comment: @Ishita why don't you chain your jQuery methods? What does actually this line do `if($(images[i]).hasClass('show')) {` ?

Comment: Ohh i see, .show { display: block; } and .hide { display: none; } are only specifying what show and hide do in general so that the javascript function understands it. Thanks again